# File is not correctly uploaded using POST-request

Tags: java, android, http-post, okhttp

I am trying to upload a .zip file from an Android phone using a POST-request. I found through some scouting through the forums okhttp which should make it quite easy.

The file that arrives at the server is a zip-file with the correct name, but there is no content in the file (it is 0kb). I suspect that the stream is not correctly flushed when sending by okhttp.

```
public class FileSender extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String zipPath = params[0];
    String zipName = params[1];
    String serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.109:5000"+"/files/"+zipName;
    File file = new File(zipPath+zipName);
    Log.d("File name", "zipName: "+zipName+" file.getName(): "+file.getName());

    // TODO file is not send properly...
    RequestBody postBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart(zipName, file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), file))
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(serverUrl)
            .post(postBody)
            // TODO insert API-key here
            .addHeader("API-key", "<my-api-key>")
            .build();


    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Request Submitted";

}}
```

I basically implemented it with  [this](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp), [this](https://medium.com/buglens/okhttp-cheatsheet-42ec6ba116b8) as template.

Am I doing something wrong? What is another way to upload files this way?

Using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) I am able to send files and there the Content-Type is also "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. The issue was on my Flask-server side. This is the code that accepts the file:

```
@api.route("/files", methods=["POST"])
def post_file():
    """Upload a file."""
    zipfile = request.files["zip"]
    filename = secure_filename(zipfile.filename)
    # Check if user has correct key
    user_key = request.headers.get("API-key")
    if user_key not in ALLOWED_KEYS:
        return f"Permission denied. Key '{user_key}' has no access.", 401

    if "/" in filename:
        # Return 400 BAD REQUEST
        abort(400, "no subdirectories directories allowed")

    zipfile.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, filename))
    # Before I tried this (which does not work):
    # with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, secure_filename(filename)), "wb") as fp:     
    #     fp.write(request.data)

    # Return 201 CREATED
    return "Successfully uploaded file.", 201
```

Here the code of my Android side:

```
public class FileSender extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    String zipPath = params[0];
    String zipName = params[1];
    // TODO put ip in env-variable
    String serverUrl = "http://IP:Port"+"/files";
    File file = new File(zipPath+zipName);
    Log.d("File name", "zipName: "+zipName+" file.getName(): "+file.getName());
    RequestBody postBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("zip", file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/zip"), file))
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(serverUrl)
            .post(postBody)
            // TODO insert API-key here
            .addHeader("API-key", "<API-Key>")
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d("SendToServer", "Worked: "+response.body().string());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("SendToServer", "Error: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

}